# How can I use htaccess to redirect a URL based on it's segments?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have some old URLs that have since changed. Right now they are going to my 404 page, so I need to redirect them to the new URLs. The original URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/en/blog/events-private/name-of-event
```

The new URLs look like this, without the "blog" segment:

```
http://example.com/en/events-private/name-of-event
```

This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/en/blog/events-private/(.*) /en/events-private/$1
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using mod_rewrite but this seems to work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/blog/events-private/(.*) /en/events-private/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/en/blog/events-private/(.*) /en/events-private/$1
> ```

In `.htaccess` the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path after the directory-prefix (that leads to the `.htaccess` file) has first been removed. The directory-prefix always ends in a slash, so the URL-path that is matched here never starts with a slash. In other words, you simply need to remove the slash prefix:

```
RewriteRule ^en/blog/events-private/(.*) /en/events-private/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(and don't forget the `R` and `L` flags.)

Note that this contrasts the use of mod_rewrite in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context. In this *context* you do need the slash prefix! Because in a *server* context, the *pattern* matches against the full URL-path.

Also, the `RewriteBase` directive in this example is superfluous (since you aren't using a relative *substitution*). And the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper should probably be removed (unless this is intended to function on systems without mod_rewrite).